# Creating texture in Vertex shader and passing to Fragment to achieve smudging brush with Metal?

Tags: ios, shader, metal, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to add a smudge effect to my paint brush project. To achieve that, I think I need to sample the the current results (which is in `paintedTexture`) from the start of the brush stroke coordinates and pass it to the fragment shader.

I have a vertex shader such as:

```
vertex VertexOut vertex_particle(
                 device Particle *particles [[buffer(0)]],
                 constant RenderParticleParameters *params [[buffer(1)]],
                 texture2d<half> imageTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                 texture2d<half> paintedTexture [[ texture(1) ]],
                 uint instance [[instance_id]])
{
    VertexOut out;
```

Drawing a fragment shader such as:

```
fragment half4 fragment_particle(VertexOut in [[ stage_in ]],
               half4 existingColor [[color(0)]],
               texture2d<half> brushTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
               float2 point [[ point_coord ]]) {
```

Is it possible to create a clipped texture from the `paintedTexture` and send it to the fragment shader?

`paintedTexture` is the current results that have been painted to the canvas. I would like to create a new texture from `paintedTexture` using the same area as the brush texture and pass it to the fragment shader.

The `existingColor [[color(0)]]` in the fragment shader is of no use since it is the current color, not the color at the beginning of a stroke. If I use existingColor, it's like using transparency (or a transfer mode based on what math is used to combine it with a new color).

If I am barking up the wrong tree, any suggestions on how to achieve a smudging effect with Metal would potentially be acceptable answers.

Update: I tried using a texture2d in the `VertexOut` struct:

```
struct VertexOut {
    float4 position   [[ position ]];
    float  point_size [[ point_size ]];
    texture2d<half> paintedTexture;
}
```

But it fails to compile with the error:

```
vertex function has invalid return type 'VertexOut'
```

It doesn't seem possible to have an array in the `VertexOut` struct either (which isn't nearly as ideal as a texture, but it could be a path forward):

```
struct VertexOut {
    float4 position   [[ position ]];
    float  point_size [[ point_size ]];
    half4 paintedPixels[65536];
}
```

Gives me the error:

```
type 'VertexOut' is not valid for attribute 'stage_in'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for shaders to **create** textures. They could fill an existing one, but I don't think that's what you want or need, here.

I would expect you could pass `paintedTexture` to the fragment shader and use the vertex shader to note where, from that texture, to sample. So, just coordinates.